# Are the attributes tab and properties tab in Android Studio the same?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm really new to Android development and this Android Studio (3.4.1). After consuming a lot of tutorials from multiple sites (with various Android Studio versions), I realize that there is a tab called "properties" in the design section. Sadly, I think I'm missing it because there is only "attributes" tab.

I have searched a lot on how to show the "properties" tab, but it didn't help me, nor mention the "attributes" tab/ I have also explored the settings and couldn't find anything about these 2 tabs.

So then I started to wonder if "properties" and "attributes" tab are just the same, but I'm not sure enough because the web's properties tab and my attributes tab look different and have different functions.

Please let me know if they are really different, and if so what I should do to have both tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since new Android Studio 3.1.2, the name of the Properties Windows is `Attributes`.

take a look at this picture:
[image: Attributes basic view]